# Why does Visual Studio report exception as unhandled for Func parameters?

Tags: c#, exception, delegates

Why is the exception thrown in this example reported as unhandled by Visual Studio when running in debug mode?

```
public bool bar(string pVal)
{
     throw new Exception("hello there");
}

public void foo(Func<string,bool> pFunc)
{
    try {
        pFunc("test");
    } catch(Exception) {
        // should be caught
    }
}

// passing bar to foo as a callable causes unhandled exception
foo(bar);
```

If I run this in the debugger, then the exception thrown in `bar()` is unhandled. The debugger will continue to the catch after stopping on the exception.

I wrote a function like `foo()` in my unit tests to help automate exception testing, but it doesn't work. Can someone explain why this doesn't work, and if it's possible to fix it.

Comment: how do you identify a fact that exception is not handled ?

Comment: @Tigran in the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: @Tigran oh, I might be wrong here. If I run the unit test is debug mode the exception is reported as unhandled, but if I run it in release then the unit test works as excepted.

Comment: The exception **is** caught in your example.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: It should work fine in your unit tests. The debugger may think it's unhandled for some reason (although it sounds odd to me) but when running tests it should be fine. Not necessarily a good idea, but it should work.

Comment: I just tested it, outputting the exception to Console.WriteLine() and I could not replicate (i.e. the exception was thrown).

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify. It's causing the unit tests to stop when running in debug mode.

Comment: sounds like your problem is with the unit test itself, this code is as expected

Comment: this is, I believe, also explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054653/generic-func-as-parameter-to-base-method

Comment: Do you have the debugger set to break on exceptions - even handled ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a quick test and the exception **IS** being caught:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foo(bar);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static bool bar(string pVal)
        {
            throw new Exception("hello there");
        }

        public static void foo(Func<string, bool> pFunc)
        {
            try
            {
                pFunc("test");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: "+ ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: confirmed.  same result here

Comment: When happens if you run this in debug mode in Visual Studio? I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: behavior is the same in debug or release modes.  your problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can switch off break on exceptions in Ctrl+Alt+E

Answer (score 1):

Your debugger may be set to break when exceptions are thrown. That would cause the behavior you're reporting. You can instead configure the debugger to only break on user-handled exceptions.

Look under Debug-->Exceptions. Here's what the dialog looks like:
[image: VS debug exceptions dialog]

You can read a great deal more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d14azbfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).